# network.request invalid URL in Corona SDK

Tags: image, url, lua, coronasdk, google-docs-api

I am working with the google developer resources to download images into my corona sdk app.
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource

I have been able to download the image as long as the URL is given. However, when I make the image ID a variable, I get the following error:

Invalid Parameter: URL argument was malformed URL

This URL works:

```
imgRequest = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

This URL doesn't:

```
imgID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
imgRequest = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id="..imgID
```

To download it I use:

```
network.download( imgRequest, "GET", imgListener, "pic.png", system.DocumentsDirectory )
```

The frustration comes when I print out both the concatenated URL and the one that has already been put together, and I get the same result. Anybody have suggestions of what to try next?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe there are some extra characters. In addition to printing urls, try comparing them to see if they are actually the same.

Comment: You are right! After trying everything I could think of, I realized there was an additional line printed afterwards, I had checked for possible spaces but not lines... I found that weird because I am using string.sub() to shorten the ID earlier... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be something else at play; can you provide a minimally working example that exhibits this issue?

I've tried both URLs and I don't get the error on any of them. I'm testing in the simulator using Corona daily build v2015.2576 on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was an additional line being printed out after the image ID, which of course would cause an invalid URL.